# Laravel api basic auth - remember password

Tags: javascript, php, rest, authentication

I've build a Laravel api and i use the auth.basic middleware to enable Basic Authentication. This means that i need to send the authorization header for each request i do if i understand it correctly.

I considered the option to store the Basic authentication token in local storage, but that isn't an option since it can be decoded by others.
Could you tell me how a Remember me function for basic authentication should work? I've also tried Laravel passport with the implicit grant but that confuses me to much to implement it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what problem your try to solve? Do you need to use basic auth or is it just the first auth that you used? Are you consuming your own api, or is it a "public" api for everyone (changing the requirements for the authentication)?

Comment: I don't need basic authentication, something else would be fine too. I have a javascript app that is going to use the api. It will request data and update that data in mysql. That's what you mean with "consuming my own api"? Users must be able to log in and get some details about product models and work with them (crud).

Comment: You could use the default auth scaffolding that comes with laravel via `php artisan make:auth`. This uses sessions/cookie authentication and does not rely on usernam and password stored in the browser. If you want to expose the api to the public for other people to use, you should still consider using oauth2 with laravel passport.

Comment: make:auth creates blade templates and those templates i can't practically use for angular. I don't want my angular app entangled with my laravel app code via blade templates.

oauth is an option but i don't know for sure which grant to implement. Implicit seems the way to go but with an implicit grant i authenticate a single user and not all of them. How would you solve this.

The other most likely option is the password grant but that grant returns refresh tokens that need to be stored securely and that's not possible in javascript

Comment: You dont need to use the templates but all the other classes that come with it. After your comment is seems more and more that you should use oauth2. This solves the problem that you want so solve!

Comment: Ok thank you so much for your information. The reason that i did not want to use oAuth is because the password grant uses a client id and secret that you need to store somewhere and at first sight i thought it was javascript. But you cant store it secturely there. I learned that the way it should work i think is that you create a laravel route to a controller and do a request to the /oauth/token  route with the username and password that you'd get from javascript AND the client id and secret that you can get from a laravel config file. In that way they remain secret like it should.

Comment: I tried implementing the strategy like mentioned in previous comment and i think it should work. But it does not work yet. With a dd i can see that it reaches the controller where i do the post request to oath/token. But at the moment the application uses guzzle to send the post request it freezes when i use postman to post the username and password to the controller. The route to the controller uses the default api and auth:api middlewares. Any suggestions in how to fix this?

Comment: Yes this is one way. Im not sure if its implemented in passport but in the specs it says that you dont need to send client secret with the password grant! The phpleague oauth server package has implemented it that way! This is what i am using on one of my projects!

Comment: Ok nice. Got it working partially. When you use php artisan server you cannot somehow send a post request to oauth because te request wil be stuck forever. I needed to create a virtual host for this.

Now i get an access_token refresh_token and expires_at back. But how can i securely store the refresh token client side? I want to use an encrypted cookie for that but when i do this in laravel:

    return response(['refresh_token' => $refresh_token, 'access_token' => $access_token, 'expires_at' => $expires])->withCookie(cookie('refresh_token', $refresh_token));

It wont give me the cookie

Comment: According to the docs you just need to do `response()->cookie(name, value,...)` https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies

Comment: Ok thanks. That works a little bit. I do get a set-cookie header back in my angular app that now contains an encrypted refresh token. I am using chrome and it is not visible in Application > Cookies > <domain i am using> in the developers pane. Do i need to set it manually by somehow reading the headers of the response? It isn't a httpOnly cookie btw. When i console log the response it is just json text and not an object i would expect that has headers. I am using a post request like this:

    
`http.post<int>('/api/v1/test').subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response)
    });`